# Why is this regex not causing an error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a bit confused about different regex formats.

The following methods are causing an error.

```
function validateDate(str)  {
    var expr = /^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/](0?[13578]|1[02])[\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\/](0?[13456789]|1[012])[\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\/]0?2[\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(29[\/]0?2[\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00)))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$/;
    return validate(expr, str);
}

function validateTime(str)  {
    var expr = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|[2]?[0-3])\:([0-5][0-9])$/;
    return validate(expr, str);
}

function validate(pattern, str) {
    return str.match(pattern);
}
```

I've taken the following regex's from the web. I think the problem is regarding certain escape characters

What's wrong here?

Thanks : )

Comment: Using such nazi regexp as in date validation is just asking for troubles. I am sure there are much shorter and simpler variants that do good enough job (js validation can't be trusted anyway).

Comment: @serg555: You need something like that to handle leap years. If you just want to validate the format and not test if it's a valid date you can just use `^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d$`, but that would consider 54/76/0000 as a valid date...

Comment: @Guffa: I think it would be much easier to split date into components using simple regexp like `^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$` and then do required checks in js. That what I would do anyway :)

Comment: I'm with @serg555: that's not a regex, it's a parlor trick.

Answer (score 3):

In the `validateDate` function you are assigning the regular expression object to the `exp` variable, but in the next line you are using the `expr` variable, which is undefined.

#### Edit:

What do you expect the functions to return? Right now they are returning an array of matches. If you want them to just return true or false, you might want to use the `test` method instead:

```
function validate(pattern, str) {
  return pattern.test(str);
}
```

Comment: done. But that's not all. There's still something wrong. I've replaced `\d` with `\\d` .. still no luck.

Comment: Don't replace `\d` with `\\d`, then you will match the two characters backslash and "d" instead of digits. Escaping backslashes is what you do if you have the pattern in a string. What kind of error are you talking about? What happens? Do you get any error message?